# Text position based on another Text

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot a vertical text (text 2) next to a horizontal text (text 1), if I use the the same position that I used to plot text1 they become superimposed.

I've tried to infer the second position based on the Extent property of text1, but I can't get the units right:

```
rec = txt.Extent;
pos_x = rec(1) + rec(3);
pos_y = rec(2); 
text(pos_x,pos_y,txt2,'HorizontalAlignment','center','FontSize',sz,'Rotation',90,'Units','normalized');
```

I've tried also with units in pixels but that didn't worked either.

The figure is a time series, I couldn't find any convertion function.

From the documentation it seems to me that the Extent values are normalized but I dont know if anything else is needed to display the second position on those coordinates.

Comment: Try using `txt.Position` rather than `Extent`.

Comment: @MrAzzaman I've tried that with the same results, Position and Extent share the same kind of units (apparently) which as far as I understand are normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Does this look like what you want to do
[plot with rotated text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xlgak.png)

Here is the code to make the above plot

```
plot(1:1.2)
h1 = text(1,1, 'Text String 1', 'verticalalignment', 'bottom');
rec = h1.Extent;
pos_x = rec(1) + rec(3);
pos_y = rec(2) + rec(4); 
text(pos_x,pos_y,'Text String 2','HorizontalAlignment','left','FontSize',10,'Rotation',90,'verticalalignment', 'bottom');
```